QField - can not edit attributes on local layer
When I open a specific local file in QField, I don't see the letter A with the pencil to edit. In another file, I can see it and I can edit the attributes. How is this possible?
I have made sure the layer is not Read Only.

I notice there is a difference when I send the data in zip-file or not. I think de zip-file is not editable. Could that be the reason?

Make sure that the layer is marked as editable in the QField Sync export settings
